# Table-cell with content that flows over two pages with row span > 1

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

(with a renderer based upon FOP 1.0)

I am trying to let a cell flow happily onto two pages while it is also set to span several rows

*this is a heavily simplified code extract:*

```
<fo:table height="210mm" width="100%">
<fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="127mm"/>
<fo:table-column column-number="2" column-width="10mm"/>
<fo:table-column column-number="3" column-width="160mm"/>

<fo:table-body>
    <fo:table-row height="100mm">
        <fo:table-cell background-color="lime" number-rows-spanned="6">
            <fo:block>
                lots & lots of text
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell background-color="blue"/>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:external-graphic scaling="non-uniform" height="100mm" width="160mm" src="./image1.jpg"/>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-row height="10mm"/>
    <fo:table-row height="100mm">
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:external-graphic scaling="non-uniform" height="100mm" width="160mm" src="./image2.jpg"/>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
    <!-- have tried and removed break-before="page" -->
    <fo:table-row height="100mm">
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:external-graphic scaling="non-uniform" height="100mm" width="160mm" src="./image3.jpg"/>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-row height="10mm"/>
    <fo:table-row height="100mm">
        <fo:table-cell/>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:external-graphic scaling="non-uniform" height="100mm" width="160mm" src="./image4.jpg"/>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</fo:table-body>
```

with a little text in cell 1 it will not place the '*lime*' across to the second page

with more than a pages worth of text - i do not get output at all!!

Is it me or the renderer that is not upto the job? :-)

Comment: The renderer, its not up to the job.

Comment: so that first cell scenario would/should work with a normal renderer then?